# PHP function errors not showing

Tags: php, arrays, function

I wasn't entirely sure how to search for this question, so if it has been asked before please send me in the right direction.

I have a validation function with an array. Inside my array I have set up errors to be displayed if one of the form fields doesn't validate. If the user fills a field out wrong, they should get an error of which field was wrong and the form should be still present. However, they get a blank page with only the generic error (the one I echo when I called the function) and not the field-specific error.  Can someone please tell me where I went wrong?

```
$output_form = 1; //control if form displays - yes
$error_text = ''; 

//declare form elements (empty first load)
$fname = '';
$valid_fname = 0;
$fname_regex = '/^([A-Z]|[a-z]){2,15}$/';
$fname_error_message = 'First name must be 2-15 alphabetic characters only.<br>';

$lname = '';
$valid_lname = 0;
$lname_regex = '/^([A-Z]|[a-z]){2,15}$/';
$lname_error_message = 'Last name must be 2-15 alphabetic characters only.<br>';

$phone = '';
$valid_phone = 0;
$phone_regex = '/^\(\d{3}\)\d{3}-\d{4}$/';
$phone_error_message = 'Phone number must be in (xxx)xxx-xxxx format.<br>';


$city = '';
$valid_city = 0;
$city_regex = '/^([A-Z]|[a-z]){2,15}$/';
$city_error_message = 'City must be 2-15 alphabetic characters only.<br>';

$state = '';
$valid_state = 0;
$state_regex = '/^([A-Z]|[a-z]){2}$/';
$state_error_message = 'State must be 2 alphabetic characters only.<br>';

//data posted
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if ($debug) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($_POST);
        echo "</pre>";
    }//end debug

    $fname = trim($_POST['fname']);
    $lname = trim($_POST['lname']);
    $phone = trim($_POST['phone']);
    $city = trim($_POST['city']);
    $state = trim($_POST['state']);

    $phone_replace = preg_replace('/[\(\)\-\s]/', '', $phone);

    function validate_form($fields, &$errors = []) {
        $errors = [];
        foreach ($fields as $name => $field) {
            if (!preg_match ($field['regex'], $field['value'])) {
                $errors[$name] = $field['error'];
                $output_form = 1;
            }
        }
        return empty($errors); //returns true/false
    }

    $fields = [
        'fname' => ['regex' => $fname_regex, 'value' => $fname, 'error' => $fname_error_message],
        'lname' => ['regex' => $lname_regex, 'value' => $lname, 'error' => $lname_error_message],
        'phone' => ['regex' => $phone_regex, 'value' => $phone, 'error' => $fname_error_message],
        'city' => ['regex' => $city_regex, 'value' => $city, 'error' => $city_error_message],
        'state' => ['regex' => $state_regex, 'value' => $state, 'error' => $state_error_message],
    ];
    $errors = [];
    if (!validate_form($fields, $errors)) {
        echo "<p>One of your fields is invalid. Please check and re-submit.</p>";
        $output_form = 1;
        return (false);
    }
    else {
        $output_form = 0;
    }
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: the only actual output is the `echo` of your general error message for the form. You never output `$errors` anywhere, unless that part of the code is missing here it's clear why you don't see them.

Comment: Why pass `$errors` by reference and then make it empty?

Comment: What is the correct way to output the $errors?  I know that's what I'm missing, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Try using some 3rd party libraries and don't reinvent the wheel https://github.com/Respect/Validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($errors as $error) echo "<p>$error</p>";
```

Actually outputting stuff usually helps ;)

Comment: Is this a separate foreach or do I need to modify my current foreach?

Comment: Validation could be apply in both Client End and Server End. It is the best practice. 
After submit the form, you will get the Array and match which field data is submitted and which not. Show the Field which data is not submitted. You could keep a Span tag to show the validation failed data.